# Correct usage of "of course you (do/are)"

Tags: grammaticality, verbs, progressive-aspect

In this exchange:

A: *I'm having trouble finding my car.*

B: *Of course you are.*

I think this sentence could also be used, keeping the same meaning: *Of course you do.*

I don't see any difference between the two, but I feel like there should be? If it is, under what circumstances would you use the *do* version?

( Is there a rule for that? )

Comment: You always use the same verb:  *I **am** having trouble...* -> "Of course you **are**"

Comment: @Jim - please make that an answer. I started to write the same thing as an answer before I noticed your comment.

Comment: @T.E.D.- go ahead.  I think the answer needs a bit more fleshing out than that simple sentence including a discussion of "do support"  and a few more examples.  I'm at work right now and don't have time.

Comment: I think [How widely-accepted is “What do you got?” to Americans?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/87570/) is highly relevant here, if not an actual duplicate. It seems to me OP's example is precisely the kind of usage where at least *some* Americans use ***do***. Which grates on me, since from my perspective only ***are*** works (or in other contexts, ***have***).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compare

> Of course you do having trouble finding your car.

with

> Of course you are having trouble finding your car.

If A uses “having” (present continuous?), then B's answer should be in the same tense.

The other form would be:

> A: I have trouble finding my car.
>
> B: Of course you do.

Comment: Your examples make it very clear. I can't believe I didn't try saying it in a full sentence: *Of course you do having trouble finding your car* which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3):

**Rule One**: If the verb is modal*, then match the verb:

The verb used is *to be* (*I am*/*I'm*, *You are*/*You're*/, *He is*, etc.) because the verb in the first sentence is *am* though contracted to *I'm*.

The response therefore would use that verb too, but in the second person; *you are* or *you're*.

We tend not to end on contractions, so "Of course you're" would be strange, and so it's "Of course you are".

**Rule Two**: If the verb is not an modal, then you use *do*.

> I found my car.
>
> *Of course you found. [Incorrect]
>
> Of course you did.

**Rule Three**: If the verb is not followed by an object or preposition, and ends the sentence, then you can choose between the two:

> I don't dance.
>
> Of course you dance.
>
> Of course you don't.

---

*The modal verbs are *be*, *can*, *could*, *dare*, *do*, *may*, *might*, *must*, *need*, *ought*, *shall*, *should*, *will* and *would*.