# Why was the indirect speech not used in the following sentence?

Tags: tenses, indirect-speech

> The witness said that he **heard** two bullets being shot before he noticed two men running down the street

The sentence contains both, reported speech and sequel of actions. Therefore I believe that pluperfect tense should have been used, however, this sentence origins from a C2 - Level English book, therefore I am confused.

Comment: Backshifting (to the past perfect "had heard") is the default option since it provides, strictly speaking, a more faithful report in that it uses the same time of orientation as the original speaker, but there is the option of retaining the original preterite ("heard"), so the C2 book is not actually wrong.

Comment: @BillJ: I'd say the book ***is*** actually "right". It reflects [the usage most common among native speakers](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=saw+it+before+he%2Chad+seen+it+before+he&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=20&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Csaw%20it%20before%20he%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Chad%20seen%20it%20before%20he%3B%2Cc0). It's *ESL* students who always seem to want to use pluperfect in contexts where it's entirely unnecessary (as in the cited context, where the sequence is pragmatically obvious as well as being explicitly indicated by the word *before*).

Comment: @FumbleFingers I'd go along with that. I did say the book was not wrong (or it's "right" if you prefer), but backshift is fine too. I too like the simplicity of retaining the original simple preterite (especially with the time marker "before"), but I don' think the sky will fall if the OP uses his preferred past perfect.

Comment: @BillJ: True, but I'm also active on [English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/) (which I've voted for migration to), and at a rough guess I reckon at least half of all questions there regarding pluperfect simply wouldn't arise if nns would just get used to the idea that it's nowhere near as "necessary" as they tend to think.

Comment: @FumbleFingers But I believe in the example given both pluperfect and simple past are valid, though in slightly different circumstances. If the report *the witness said he heard* comes immediately following the witness's evidence, or it is the first time it is new information, then past is the tense to use. But anyone reporting a year later might well say *the witness said he had heard*.

Comment: @WS2: Hmm. I think you're just attracted to pluperfect there because of its association with "more distant past". Which is perfectly valid as a creative (literary?) device, if not overused. But that's not how many *learners* see things, and there's a world of difference between the two perspectives. I can easily imagine a good writer using pluperfect in a context as outined by you, but suppose we switch to *direct* speech from the witness: *"I **had heard** two bullets being shot before I noticed two men running"*. I think you *really* have to contrive things to make that one credible.

Comment: What are you asking? That sentence does use indirect speech.

Comment: @curiousdannii: I'm not *asking* anything. I'm simply pointing out that if we consider the actual words uttered by the witness giving rise to the reported speech in the question text, it's unlikely he would actually have used pluperfect himself. Not that it's necessarily "wrong" to use pluperfect when reporting what he said later, but I think to a considerable extent it represents (over-)use of a literary form that wouldn't occur anywhere near as often in the "real-world" context it supposedly represents.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I was addressing the OP... this question is not very clear IMO.

Comment: @curiousdannii: The question clearly states that OP think his cited text *should* use pluperfect, so by implication he wants us confirm his preconception and dismiss the example as "sloppy, incorrect" (or give some *other* explanation as to why the writer got it "wrong"). So far as *I'm* concerned, this is a typical case of an nns failing to appreciate that native speakers in general tend to avoid complex tense forms where they're not *necessary* (or failing to understand exactly *when* the complex forms are unnecessary). So it's essentially an ELL question.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Ok - there are circumstances in which I would not use it, but also ones in which I would. *I had heard that he was a lawyer,so I asked his advice*.  *And if I had known that this would become such a matter of dispute, I would have given further examples from the start*.

Comment: @WS2: On average I tend to prefer the simpler verb forms, so your first one there would usually just be *I heard that he was a lawyer,so...* for me. But for the "past tense irrealis" of the second one, I'd almost always say *If **I'd have** known that, **I'd've** done something else*. Though if you *forced* me to fully expand, it would be *If I **had have** known that...,* and sod the grammarians. I can't stand *If I **would have** known that* any more than [John Lawler can stand my version!](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/62490/2637) :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Oh, I enjoy the pluperfect. *If I had heard...* strikes quite a different nuance to *If I heard...* but I agree with your view entirely about *if I had have known* versus *If I would have known* (ugh!) - perhaps because, old boy, we are British!

Comment: @WS2: Erm... Aren't we old enough to call each other *old **bean**?* :) The point is I don't think you and I are in any meaningful sense *arguing* about whether one usage or the other is "right, wrong" - we're just *discussing* our own personal preferences. Which is what I'd expect from a couple of *(**serious**) English language enthusiasts* (neither of us being exactly "professionals" in this area). But OP's question is predicated on the assumption that it *is* a matter of right/wrong, which I think means it belongs on ELL, not here.