# Why do conditional sentences with "would have had to" have an extra "had" in them?

Tags: conditionals, modal-verbs, perfect-aspect, continuous-aspect, esl

Well, I was reading about Type Three conditionals. In the main clause we use *if* + past perfect (*had*), then in the second clause we use either the "perfect conditional" or the "perfect continuous conditional".

- If past perfect, then conditional perfect.
- If past perfect, then conditional perfect continuous.

Why then do some sentences use *would have had* in the main clause?

> 1. If it had rained, you **would have gotten** wet.
> 2. For example, if it **had not been** for the aid received by the European countries after World War II from the US under the Marshal Plan, they **would have had to struggle** tremendously to reach where they are today.

Could you please clear up the difference between **would have** and **would have had**?

Can the second sentence be written without *had* in its main clause?

Comment: See [this comment](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/501296/difference-between-if-i-were-and-if-i-would-be#comment1210184_501296) on an earlier related question: *There are lots and lots of native speakers in North America who say **If I would be your pupil ...** It means exactly the same thing as **If I were your pupil ...*** On the basis of which I guess they might also say *If it **would have** rained, you would have gotten wet.* (Just don't ask me whether Americans use ***got*** or ***gotten*** there; that's too complicated for me as a mere Brit! :)

Comment: ***they would have had to struggle*** is approximately an alternative to ***they would have struggled***, but the former incorporates ***to have to = to be obliged to***, which *may* make a nuance of difference to some.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: I know of *nobody* in North America who says "If I would be your pupil." That locution has "non-native speaker" written all over it.

Comment: @Robusto: I was extrapolating from [“If I would have lost you” vs “If I had lost you”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/62482/if-i-would-have-lost-you-vs-if-i-had-lost-you), which looks to me like the same general pattern. But I don't really understand such usages anyway (I'd only ever say *If **I'd have** lost you*, which I internally "unpack" as *If **I had have** lost you*, but apparently that's not acceptable to grammarians). If you say I'm making a mistake somewhere along the line, I'm happy to believe you.

Comment: No one seems to say what is obvious here: He **would have had to work harder**, if  his family **had been poor** = said about the past. "He **would have to work harder**, if his family **were poor**. said in the present about a situation in the present. People get their knickers in a grammar twist and overlook the bottom line.

Comment: Replace the "had" with "needed".

Answer (score 2):

The issue here, I think, is a confusion as to the function of *have*. It can be an auxiliary verb or a lexical verb. In the case of ***would have gotten wet*** it is an auxiliary, whereas in ***would have had to struggle*** the first instance is auxiliary and the second lexical. In both cases, auxiliary *have* puts the situation into past time and *would* marks the counter-factuality of the situation. In the second, ***had*** has a meaning similar to *must* but unlike *must* it is not a modal auxiliary.

The second sentence cannot be written without ***had*** as the ***have*** would then be interpreted as the lexical verb and no longer mark a past time situation. The struggling would then be placed in present or future time.

Comment: Are [semi-]modal usages classed as lexical? Like auxiliary 'have', semi-modal 'have to' is not considered so by some. It is very different in many respects from 'snore' or 'kick' say.

Comment: @Edwin Ashworth CaGEL classifies it as lexical as it has none of the modal auxiliary properties: only primary forms(no participles), no subject-verb agreement, only bare infinitival complement, ability to occur in remote apodosis (If it weren't for her, I _would_ give up.), modally remote preterite in main clause (I _would_ ask you to treat it seriously.)(CaGEL p108,112)

Comment: Another classification problem. 'Have to' and 'must' are at times interchangeable, and certainly close semantically. They both address epistemic, deontic and circumstantial modality.

Comment: Right: have to do something=an idiom, the non-present tenses being: /had to do something/have had to do something/would have had to do something/will have to do something, and wait for it: will have had to do something.  Oops: was having to do something. Probably forgotten some too.

Answer (score 0):

The main clause of a "Type Three conditional" has this construction:

> past-tense modal (e.g., *would*) + perfect infinitive (i.e., the infinitive form of the perfect auxiliary *have* + past participle (e.g., *gotten* or *had*))

So it's only natural that your second example has the construction of *would have had*, because this is exactly the construction of the main clause of a "Type Three conditional".

> Could you please clear up the difference between **would have** and **would have had**?

If you're comparing **would have** in your first example with **would have had** in your second example, then you're comparing two different things, because you should be instead comparing **would have gotten** in your first example with **would have had** in your second example, in which case I'm sure you don't see any difference between the two.

> Can the second sentence be written without *had* in its main clause?

If you simply omit *had*, you get this:

> ...they **would have to struggle** tremendously to reach where they are today.

This is NOT the construction of the main clause of a "Type Three conditional", because you don't have the perfect infinitive. So, no, the second sentence can't be written without *had* in its main clause, unless you're going to make the second example something other than a "Type Three conditional".

Answer (score 0):

I support Lambie's comment.

When we use "would have"(would + infinitive) we speak or imagine about present or past.
For example I don't have a car. My friend invites me to visit him. And I say,
****"I would visit you (now), if I had a car (now)".**** This is about the current situation or about the possible one in the future.

But let's take a scene, when I regret about something in the past. A completed action, which is not possible to change. So my friend invited me and I didn't go to him. He asks me why.
I can say as a regret,
****"If I had got a car (in the past), I would have visited you (in the past).**** We try to imagine that past action in a different way or with a different ending.

Answer (score 0):

**Would have** is referring to what, hypothetically, would have happened.

**Would have had to** is the same except that in addition it imports the idea of necessity or obligation. i.e. **would have had to** means **would have been compelled to** or **would have been obliged to** or **would have needed to**

Answer (score -1):

It gets easier if you concentrate on the past-tense actions:

would have 'gotten wet'      ('gotten' implies past-tense)

would have 'had to struggle'  ('had to' implies past-tense)

in contrast:

would have 'to struggle'  ('to struggle' does not imply past-tense)