# How to differentiate the short form of "would" and "had"?

Tags: abbreviations, past-perfect, would

How do you differentiate:

I'd always longed to see... = I would always longed to see...

VS

I'd always longed to see.. = I had always longed to see..

Comment: Not the same: I'd always **long** to see... = I would always **long** to see... If the same, more context will reveal the full story.

Comment: _I would always longed_ is meaningless, so it can't mean that.

Comment: [Most people](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/62490/2637) unpack *If **I'd have** lost you, I don't know what I would have done* as ***If I would have lost you...***, but I'm by no means the only person who thinks of it as ***If I had have lost you...***

Answer (score 2):

Both the auxiliary verbs ***would*** and ***had*** contract to ***'d***, usually with pronoun subjects: *he'd, I'd, you'd, she'd, it'd, they'd, we'd*. Whether spoken or written, you can't tell which one it is, if you only have the contraction.

But you **can** tell the difference if you notice what comes next.
Like all auxiliary verbs, each of these must be followed by a particular verb form.

- *Would*, like all modal auxiliary verbs, must be followed by an **Infinitive** verb form:
  *I **would** always **love** to stand on the beach* (**not** **loved*).
  = ***I'd** always **love** to stand on the beach*
- *Have* is the auxiliary for the Perfect, and takes a **Past Participle** verb form:
  *I **had** always **loved** to stand on the beach* (**not** **love*).
  = ***I'd** always **loved** to stand on the beach*

Answer (score 0):

In similar uses, the meaning is realized. But generally, it is known what use it is as a structure. For example, "Would" is usually used with the perfect infinitive (have + past participle), while "Had" is used with the past participle.

In your example, the sentence with had seems correct. Because it should be used as "would always v1".